# mono - xamarin studio System.MissingMethodException

Tags: xamarin, monodevelop

As the title says when I start the project it gives System.MissingMethodException but then I hit refresh on browser and it works. What is the problem with first start ?

.net 4.5 and mvc 4

```
System.MissingMethodException
Method 'HostingEnvironment.get_InClientBuildManager' not found.
```

and also `System.Web.Entity` not found in references

and also after I hit refresh it brings the login page and I enter name password then returns

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object`
```

doesnt even control name or password. Project works on visual studio. and it is connected to the server not local host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MissingMethodException is because Mono's System.Web assembly didn't have the equivalent InClientBuildManager property from MS.NET. This is a mono bug, and has been recently [fixed](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/58e0608c10c621b15fd9f396f8e46c567891b231) in the master branch.

So I recommend you to wait for Mono 4.3/4.4 or use the weekly packages provided by Xamarin.

Comment: what are those weekly packages ? do you have a link or easy steps to fix it ? When mono 4.3/4.4 will be out where can I follow ? @knocte